# How to check which installation media is used in a script

Tags: shell-script, system-installation, suse

I'm using AutoYast to install SUSE 11 SP4.
Inside of the autoyast control file you can write scripts at multiple stages.

My script runs during the `<post-scripts>` stage and looks like so:

```
mkdir /media/usb
echo "Mounting USB to /media/usb"
mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
echo "Copying Contents to /root/LINUX_DVD/"
mkdir /root/LINUX_DVD/
cp -aR /media/usb/. /root/LINUX_DVD/
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Copy: OK"
    cd /root/LINUX_DVD/seconet/setup/
    sed -e "s/passwd service/echo -e '******' | passwd --stdin service/" install.sh > install_tmp.sh
    mv install_tmp.sh install.sh
    chmod +x install.sh
    echo "After confirmation system will finish configuration and reboot."
    echo "After the reboot the Installation script will automatically execute."
else
    echo "Copy: Failed"
    echo "Copying DVD and installing VCIP must be done manually after reboot."
    exit
fi
```

Since there's two possible installation media's (DVD & USB) I wanted to find a way to check for that in this script, because as you see I'm copying the contents.

At this stage in the installation process there's no media mounted, meaning I have to mount the installation media as well.

At first I thought I'll just check if the mounting was successful and if not I'll try the other media, but was wondering if it's plausible to see if any of the `/dev/*` has content on it and if so, just mount the right one there.

**Is it possible to check if a device in `/dev/` has content?**

**Is this approach even practical?**

This is how I solved it for now:

```
mkdir /media/install
mount /dev/sdb1 /media/install
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "USB not found, trying DVD"
    mount /dev/sr0 /media/install
    EXITCODE=$?
    if [ $EXITCODE -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "No correct installation media found";
        exit $EXITCODE;
    else
        echo "Mounted DVD"
    fi
else
    echo "Mounted USB"
fi
echo "Copying Contents to /root/LINUX_DVD/"
mkdir /root/LINUX_DVD/
cp -aR /media/install/. /root/LINUX_DVD/
... rest of the script ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are mixing things.

What do you mean by "has content" ?

If it is "has data on it", then you must mount.

But if you mean "exists" or "there's a real media behind" (as a /dev/ entry does not grant that there's a real device behind) then you can grep /proc/partitions for /dev/sdb1 or use "lsblk /dev/sdb" (and once again grep for sdb1 in the reply)

```
if grep "sdb1" /proc/partitions ; then
    echo sdb1 exists
fi
```

The problem for sr0 is that it will be present even if there's no disk in the CD/DVD drive (the drive is present, so the kernel is not lying).

From [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/630588/how-to-detect-whether-there-is-a-cd-rom-in-the-drive), it looks like "blkid /dev/sr0" should give you the answer for /dev/sr0

Comment: Yes, I think I've mixed that up a little.
I did mean "has a real media behind it"... Thanks for the answer, seems like that will do the job well.. I'll try it out during the next assembly